# A question about the delta method in asymptotic distributions

Tags: convergence, asymptotics, delta-method

I am reading up on the delta method from [its Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#:%7E:text=In%20statistics%2C%20the%20delta%20method,limiting%20variance%20of%20that%20estimator.). Under the heading [Univariate delta method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delta_method#:%7E:text=Univariate%20delta%20method%5Bedit%5D) the statement of the method is as follows:

If
$$\sqrt{n}[X_n - \theta]\xrightarrow{\text{D}} \mathcal{N}(0,\sigma^2)$$ where $X_n$ is a sequence of random variables where $\theta$ and $\sigma$ are finite valued constants and $\xrightarrow{D}$ denotes convergence in distribution, then: $$\sqrt{n}[g(X_n) - g(\theta)]\xrightarrow{\text{D}} \mathcal{N}(0,[g^{'}(\theta)^2]\sigma^2)$$ Later on to prove this they ask us to note that $X_n \xrightarrow{P}\theta$ where $\xrightarrow{P}$ denotes convergence in probability

What justifies this claim? This seems to be sort of like a reverse central limit theorem and I feel like something very basic is in my blindspot. I need your help in figuring it out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This basically follows directly from Slutsky's theorem. Below are the details.

By Slutsky's theorem, since $n^{-1/2} \to 0$ and $\sqrt{n} (X_n - \theta) \stackrel{D}{\to} N(0, \sigma^2)$, we have
\begin{equation*}
n^{-1/2} \left\{ \sqrt{n} (X_n - \theta) \right\} \stackrel{D}{\to} 0 \times N(0, \sigma^2).
\end{equation*}
Since this congergence in distribution to a constant implies convergence in probability to the same constant and since $X_n = n^{-1/2} \left\{ \sqrt{n} (X_n - \theta) \right\} + \theta$,
\begin{equation*}
 X_n \stackrel{p}{\to} 0 + \theta = \theta.
\end{equation*}

Comment: Also worth noting that $X_n \xrightarrow{P}\theta$ means that $X_n$ is a [(weakly) consistent estimator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Consistent_estimator#Definition) for $\theta$.

Comment: Wonderful! Thank you. Beats me why they'd assume it to be obvious and not even hint at the proof.